# Compare 2 files and use fuzzy wuzzy to return a table with the best match

Tags: python, dataframe, fuzzywuzzy

I have the following two datasets:

**Raw Data**
[image]

**Lookup Table**
[image]

and I am trying to use fuzzy wuzzy to create the following extract via a dataframe.

**Expected file table**
[image]

I was able to create a loop to find the correct match by using process.extract, but i can't figure out how to get it to look like the final table

I am trying to use fuzzy wuzzy to create the following extract via a dataframe.

**Expected file table**
[image]

Comment: One approach: As you find the matches put these into a Dictionary with items such as `"BATONROUGE" : "BATON ROUGE"` then create the new column from the CITY column using `df['Clean_City'] = df['City].map(my_dict)`

Comment: please share a  minimal reproducible example -  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example of  your current code. you will get many more answers if we can see the code

Comment: better put data as text with `DataFrame` so we could simply copy it - to test it in code.